# Change MySQL database upon closing the window

Tags: php, mysql

I have made this little chatting application using php and mysql,
and i wondered if a user could be logged off as soon as they closed the window. I tried using timestamps, but I can't get that to work. If someone has a little code for that, I wouldn't mind getting it :)

Comment: think that can be done with [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), by holding a connection until the windos closes, and let the server do the update when the connection is lost

Comment: Another common approach to this is to do a scheduled CRON job to see which sessions have finished, and assume log-off from that.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniters [Session class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) as something called `sess_expire_on_close` so it is possible. You can take a look at this class here: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Session.php

Comment: This doesn't work in the same way - the session is only marked for destruction and not instantly deleted.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments - comet is the right technique to use. It's basically an endless stream of AJAX calls, where you'll need to heavily depend on short timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a chat application, it's best to treat it as a service, I think. Then your service can be responsible for session management. Then the client side can make periodic calls to communicate that it's still there. If the service doesn't receive the "still here" token in `n` units of time, then the service can update the user's status to logged out.